# RestKit with Xcode4 but not as a GitHub submodule

Tags: git, xcode4, restkit

I was following the [readme](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#readme) to
get started using [RestKit](http://restkit.org). Everything works just fine when adding RestKit as a GitHub submodule.

Is there a way I can add RestKit to an already existing Xcode 4 project but not as a GitHub submodule?

The project I want to add RestKit to is not set up with GitHub repository and will actually go into a subversion repository instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just downloaded it, placed it in the root of myproject, unzipped it and renamed it to RestKit.

Comment: Hi jspooner. Thanks, did you just go github.com -> download, drag the entire folder, examples and all (15 Mb) into your Xcode project? I tried that and it seems pretty bloated.

Comment: Yep thats it.  I ran into a couple of other problems too... If you see Mach-O errors go ahead and include the files they list as optional.  Once I got it up and running it works great!  Much better than ObjectiveResource.

Comment: It seems as a complete mess to add RestKit to an existing project under subversion.. Wish they would do a "drop in source" version. Just to be sure, did you go through the linking, adding header search path, adding dependencies etc. etc. to get it running?

Comment: Yep, just replace step one with unzipping the download.  Is there an specific error your seeing?

Comment: I don't see why the configuration of RestKit should have anything to do with SVN or Git (Apart from cloning the repository)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day a [git submodule](http://help.github.com/submodules/) is merely a folder on your hard drive. However, from git's "viewpoint" it is recognized as a reference to another repository (at a specific commit) rather than a folder of files.

So if you are using git only (which you are not in this case) then it is a simple yet quite powerful mechanism of nesting projects or including libraries.

To answer your question, I guess you could do it all from the command line, which might be quicker than downloading and unzipping the source code (depending on your preference of course):

```
cd /path/to/your/project

git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git RestKit
cd RestKit
# Checkout the current stable branch
git checkout 0.9-stable
# Remove the git repository
rm -fr .git/
```

From here you can configure your project according to the [installation guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#readme)